# C# "Register COM interop" option is disabled

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am trying to create DLL out of my C# code, I found some [links](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/) that guides me to create my DLL file and use it in Excel as I wanted. One of the steps is to check the "Register COM interop" check box in the Build tab of the project.

Unfortunately, **this checkbox is always disabled**! Does anyone know how to enable it ? I am using VS 2010.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to do it from the IDE, you can just call regasm.exe yourself.

Comment: [When i create Class Library (.NET Standard) the checkbox "Register COM interop" was disable, then i create Class Library (.NET Framework) and .NET Framework 4.5 the checkbox "Register COM interop" is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBH53.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

firstly verify your output type, it must be Class Library and not Console application.

Secondly if your problem persists, open your csproj and modify your node

```
<RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried, but could not know the name of the xml node for "Register COM interop" since it does nt exist at all in the xml file of csproj

Comment: I think that you must firstly modify your output type before add the property, you can find output type in Application section, before Build

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, with the new Visual Studio 2019. The first choice for creating a Class Library is Class Library .Net framework and this will not work. You have to go down several lines to find Class Library (.NET framework) C# Windows library. This will work, provided that in project property you don't forget in Assembly Information to activate Make assembly copy visible in addition to register for com interop in build

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same problem.

What happened was when i created the project i selected the class library option that targets the .Net framework.

When i made a new project that doesn't target the .Net framework the option is enabled again.